# How to check when a certain user disconnects using socket.io?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

So I'm using sockets to connect the Minecraft protocol to a website, and I want to delete some users file when they disconnect, but how do I check when someone disconnects and get that users userid, I looked at the docs but I didn't see anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can see when a socket.io connection disconnects by listening to the `disconnect` event on the connected socket.

You don't really say what a userid is in your system.  The usual way one would keep track of something like that is to associated the userid with the socket at the time the socket connects.  How you get that userid when the socket connects depends upon the details of your system.  You might get it from a cookie or a session parameter.  You can make it easy to access from socket events by setting it as a property on the socket object such as setting `socket.userid` to the userid value.  Then, you could access that value at the time of the disconnect event.

Answer (score 0):

in your server you will need a `disconnect` event which is emitted when user is disconnected from socket i.e closes browser etc

```
socket.on('disconnect', ()=>{
  console.log(socket.id);
});
```